# Merge 2 files in ubuntu depending of an ID

Tags: ubuntu, text, debian, edit

I have 2 files :
Name.txt :
1 Smith
2 Doe
3 Kim
4 Mouse

Firstname.txt :
1 John
4 Mickey
3 Jung
3 Un
2 Jane

I want to make a file :
User.txt
1 John Smith
2 Jane Doe
3 Kim Jong Un
4 Mickey Mouse

Do you know what will be the best to do it?

I suffered enough to extract my logs from MySQL of GLPI and didn't know Ubuntu enough to find an easy solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo wget -qO /usr/local/bin/yq https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/latest/download/yq_linux_amd64
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/yq
awk 'NF{$2=":\n -" OFS $2} 1'  Name > Name1
awk 'NF{$2=":\n -" OFS $2} 1'  Firstname > Firstname1
yq eval-all '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item)' Name1 Firstname1 > Result
```

Comment: Almost good, expect it only one value per line